# oauth2-proxy and keycloak identity provider error

Tags: authentication, keycloak, oauth2-proxy

I'm right now stuck with some configuration I have in my kubernetes. In my lab I want to configure oauth2-proxy to use keycloak as an identity provider. I've everything ready but when trying to login using keycloak it shows a 403 Forbidden error "Login Failed: The upstream identity provider returned an error: invalid_scope"

Pod logs:

```
[2022/11/03 08:49:31] [oauthproxy.go:752] Error while parsing OAuth2 callback: invalid_scope

08:30:38,734 WARN [org.keycloak.events] (default task-43) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=test, clientId=oauth2-proxy, userId=null, ipAddress=10.50.21.171, error=invalid_request, response_type=code, redirect_uri=https://oauth.test.dev/oauth2/callback, response_mode=query

08:34:11,933 ERROR [org.keycloak.services] (default task-41) KC-SERVICES0093: Invalid parameter value for: scope
```

I've look for documentation and I don't see why is complaining about the scopes as I've them right.

This is my oauth2-proxy values:

```
provider = "keycloak-oidc"
provider_display_name = "Keycloak"
cookie_domains = ".test.dev"
oidc_issuer_url = "https://keycloak.test.dev/auth/realms/test"
reverse_proxy = true
email_domains = [ "*" ]
scope = "openid profile email groups"
whitelist_domains = ["test.dev",".test.dev"]
pass_authorization_header = true
pass_access_token = true
pass_user_headers = true
set_authorization_header = true
set_xauthrequest = true
cookie_refresh = "1m"
cookie_expire = "30m"`
```

And in keycloak I have the oauth2-proxy client created with Groups and Audience mappers.

I see these errors in keycloak:

```
LOGIN_ERROR

Client oauth2-proxy

Error invalid_request

response_type code

redirect_uri https://oauth.test.dev/oauth2/callback

response_mode query
```

If someone has experience with this and can point me to the right direction and tell me what I'm doing wrong I would be very grateful

Thank you

I've tried different configurations and overwriting the scope parameter in the container but still the same issue. I expect to login correctly using keycloak.

Comment: I will answer myself.
It was a scope issue indeed. Just configured the scope with email only:
`scope = "email"`.
I don't know if is because I'm using Auth0 identity provider configured inside keycloak.